# Replacing every non zero value by their index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big *pandas.DataFrame* (r:15000 c:50) in which I want to replace every non zero value by the value of their index (which is in my case a custom one consisting of floats).

I can do it with some `for` loops but it's time taking, so I was wondering if there was a command that allows it to run quicker ?

Comment: If you provide a small sample case and the desired outcome, many people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for set not matched `0` to index values:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1,3], size=(5,5)))
#sample FloatIndex
df.index /= 523
print (df)
          0  1  2  3  4
0.000000  3  1  3  3  0
0.001912  3  3  1  3  1
0.003824  3  1  0  1  3
0.005736  1  0  3  0  1
0.007648  3  1  0  0  0

df = df.where(df.eq(0), df.index)
print (df)
                 0         1         2         3         4
0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
0.001912  0.001912  0.001912  0.001912  0.001912  0.001912
0.003824  0.003824  0.003824  0.000000  0.003824  0.003824
0.005736  0.005736  0.000000  0.005736  0.000000  0.005736
0.007648  0.007648  0.007648  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get there with Pandas operations, which will be way more efficient.

Given a dataset that looks sort of like

```py
>>> df
      0    1    2    3    4
50  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
51  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
52  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
53  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
54  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

You can use a [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to perform an operation for each column, where you mask the non-zero values with [`.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and then do a [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill them with the index values.

```py
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.where(col != 0).fillna(col.index.to_series()))
       0     1     2     3     4
50   1.0  50.0   1.0   1.0  50.0
51   1.0   1.0   1.0  51.0   1.0
52   1.0  52.0  52.0   1.0  52.0
53  53.0  53.0  53.0   1.0  53.0
54   1.0  54.0   1.0  54.0  54.0
```